# git: remove 2nd commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove the 2nd commit to a repo.  At this point I could just blow away the `.git` dir and re-do it, but I'm curious how to do this...  I've deleted commits before, but apparently never the 2nd one :)

```
> git log

commit c39019e4b08497406c53ceb532f99801793205ca
Author: Me
Date:   Thu Mar 22 14:02:41 2012 -0700

    Initializing registry directories

commit 535dce28f1c68e8af9d22bc653aca426fb7825d8
Author: Me
Date:   Tue Jan 31 21:04:13 2012 -0800

    First Commit

> git rebase -i HEAD~2
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~2

> git rebase -i HEAD~1
```

at which point I get in my editor:

```
pick c39019e Initializing registry directories

# Rebase 535dce2..c39019e onto 535dce2
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Now my problem is that I can't just blow away this 2nd commit since "if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to remove the topmost commit, use `git reset --hard HEAD~`. Rebase is not needed since you are not removing anything in between other commits.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you revert your commit?

`git revert 535dce28f1c68e8af9d22bc653aca426fb7825d8`
or
`git revert HEAD~1`

Comment: how does that make a difference? Your goal of having the change removed is done.

Comment: Because I hadn't pushed yet and don't really see a point in pushing "commit", "undo previous commit".  Your answer isn't _wrong_, I just like the others better :P

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered (above) but note that in newer git, there is a `noop` command you can put in the file.  So you can replace the `pick` line with `noop`:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD^
[in editor, change pick line to noop, and write and quit]
".git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 15L, 492C written
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
$
```

Admittedly this does nothing that `git reset` does not do just as easily ... but if you've already started the interactive rebase, and you only realize what you wanted after the fact, the `noop` trick is handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

This will include the root commit in your rebase. You can then choose to `fixup`, `squash`, or delete that 2nd commit entirely if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the last commit, then you can do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

And if it is not the last commit, you would have had another commit atleast in the rebase list and you can remove the 2nd commit.